# Why does the goroutine not block for time.Sleep(duration)

Tags: go, channel

The program that I ran:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

var sleepSeconds string
var timeToSleep time.Duration

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&sleepSeconds, "sleep", "1s", "-sleep \"3s\"")
}

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Start Time: ", startTime)
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    // Block until a signal is received.
    flag.Parse()
    timeToSleep, err := time.ParseDuration(sleepSeconds)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to parse the duration: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Time to Sleep: ", timeToSleep)

    myChan := make(chan string)
    go one(myChan)
    go two(myChan)
    go three(myChan)
    var s os.Signal
    fmt.Println("Signal is, ", s)
    go func() {
        s = <-c
        fmt.Println("After receiving Signal is, ", s)

    }()
    i := 0
    for {
        i++
        generatedString := fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
        fmt.Println("Generating... ", generatedString)
        myChan <- generatedString
        //      time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
        fmt.Println("Length of Channel: ", len(myChan))
        if s != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Total time the program ran for: ", time.Since(startTime))
}

func one(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func one: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}

func two(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func two: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}

func three(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func three: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}
```

When I run this program with the following flags(5s)

`./ichan -sleep "5s" > data.txt`

output is puzzling as I see the program has only run for `2.31606525s` but all 3 goroutines are supposed to be blocked at least for 5 seconds each.
data.txt is part of this [repository](https://github.com/alwindoss/ichan) for reference, code is also available in the same repository.

**My Question is:** time.Sleep() in the functions `one`, `two` and `three` are supposed to be blocked until the duration of sleep and then consume the strings from the channel, but the observation is that sleep is not having any effect on the goroutines.

Comment: You access the `s` variable from multiple goroutines (one writes it) without synchronization: that's a data race and hence undefined behavior.

Comment: @icza The behaviour is the same even without the `s` I added `s` for a way to capture the total time that the program ran for.

Comment: If it's the same, then please provide an example without data races so we can focus on the real issue.

Comment: How did you know time.Sleep() in the functions has no block effect? What did you observe?

Comment: Please check the data.txt file in the repository. If the sleep worked the `Value received in func two: 181191` should not be printed with this value it should have been much smaller number.

However, per @icza request I have made changes to the source code and updated the repository with a new branch `no_signals_final`

Note: I see the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeToSleep, err :=` creates a new, local variable named timeToSleep that is independent of the package level variable with the same name, so the package level variable is always zero.

It seems you have missed that there is a native duration flag type: https://pkg.go.dev/flag#DurationVar

```
func init() {
    flag.DurationVar(&timeToSleep, "sleep", 1*time.Second, `-sleep "3s"`)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I confirm the problem and the solution and it works

Comment: I also did miss that the flag package had an option to accept flags as duration

Answer (score 0):

Working Copy of the same program

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

var sleepSeconds string
var timeToSleep time.Duration
var err error

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&sleepSeconds, "sleep", "1s", "-sleep \"3s\"")
}

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Start Time: ", startTime)
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)

    // Block until a signal is received.
    flag.Parse()
    timeToSleep, err = time.ParseDuration(sleepSeconds)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to parse the duration: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Time to Sleep: ", timeToSleep)

    myChan := make(chan string)
    go one(myChan)
    go two(myChan)
    go three(myChan)
    var s os.Signal
    fmt.Println("Signal is, ", s)
    go func() {
        s = <-c
        fmt.Println("After receiving Signal is, ", s)

    }()
    i := 0
    for {
        i++
        generatedString := fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
        fmt.Println("Generating... ", generatedString)
        myChan <- generatedString
        //      time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
        fmt.Println("Length of Channel: ", len(myChan))
        if s != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Total time the program ran for: ", time.Since(startTime))
}

func one(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func one: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}

func two(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func two: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}

func three(dataCh chan string) {
    for val := range dataCh {
        fmt.Printf("Value received in func three: %s\n", val)
        time.Sleep(timeToSleep)
    }
}
```